# VBA Excel Best Practices for using Forms and Classes together?

Tags: class, excel, vba

I am new to using classes and would like to learn smart ways of integrating them with forms. Specifically, when you enter data into a form, should that form be tightly linked with a class and how?

Let's use a simple example.  John is a collector of all kinds of cards: baseball cards, Pokemon cards, etc. He keeps his card list database stored in Excel worksheets and manages them using forms. There are forms for entering new cards and modifying their status in his collection, and there are also forms and functions for analyzing his data.

So he might have a clsBaseball, a clsPokemon, a clsAlbum and a clsSalesRecord. He also has forms for entering and modifying data and other types of analysis forms that compare cards, calculate stats for various teams and time periods, etc.

When John clicks the "New Baseball Card" button, his frmBaseball pops up.

1. He enters baseball card data
2. He clicks Update
3. The form is validated
4. The data is saved onto the worksheet

At any point in the above process is clsBaseball used?  I can see how the class would be used to load up all data in service of fancy sorting or statistical routines, but is it actually used during the entry phase such that the fields on the form have a direct effect on an instance of clsBaseball?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how robust your requirements are. If you're just prototyping something then tightly binding your code to your form is fine. If however you want to build a more flexible, robust and extensible application, then [modelling](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/content/RationalEdge/sep04/bell/) your data structure in classes, encapsulating your functionality in objects is the way to go.

Classes enable you to model real world things and they facilitate their implementation in a logically separated [tiered architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture). In your case your form provides the presentation layer, your classes provide the application tier, and your excel sheets provide the data tier (normally a database) - this is 3 tier.

So, in your example I would model your data in classes, as you have done, but then if I required functionality requiring all my clsBaseball objects, I would have managing classes for each object. These managing classes contain a collection of your clsBaseball objects and allow you to implement behaviour that requires a collection of objects. For example, you would implement your update method in clsBaseball, but you would implement CalculateStats in the clsBaseballs managing class, you could also call the update methods for all your clsBaseball objects by iterating over the collection of clsBaseball in (managing class) clsBaseballs.

In answer to your questions:

At any point in the above process is clsBaseball used?

1) **He enters baseball card data:**
You maybe instantiate an instance of clsBaseball, but perhaps not yet

2) **He clicks update:**
You instantiate a new instance of clsBaseball (or use the existing one), pass through the user entered values and call clsBaseball's update method. In this way you encapsulate the clsBaseball behaviour.

3) **The form is validated:**
This would occur before the clsBaseball updates the datastore. So you would probably have a validation method in clsBaseball that is called before any data is updated. Any errors can be passed back up to the presentation layer (your form). Or you could just validate in the form (though having any business logic in your presentation layer is frowned upon because you might want to switch out your presentation layer for something else, please see the [MVC/MVP patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)).

4) **The data is saved onto the worksheet:**
This is done by clsBaseball by the update method.

As for your fancy sorting or statistical routines, you could get this data from your managing classes which, because they contain collections of your objects are perfectly setup to analyse all your clsBaseball instances. All of this functionality is nicely encapsulated, there is no repetition ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)) and anyone coming newly to the code will be able to figure out what's going on.

I answered a question a little while ago re how to structure data in MS Access, the answer includes examples of a class and managing class: [MS ACCESS 2003 triggers (Query Event), and Excel import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172796/ms-access-2003-triggers-query-event-and-excel-import/17175640#17175640)

Comment: This is excellent and gives me a lot to think about. Wish I had known it before spending months on the program (actually for a refinery, not baseball cards). I may ghost some hours to convert it to this more robust style.

Comment: I keep realizing that things feel wrong as I progress. For instance, I have to keep creating hidden fields on my forms to store temporary data. I think I need to instantiate the class immediately so I can do on-the spot validation when a field is changed instead of after everything is filled in. Then I can put validation in the class, not in the form code. Make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. That way you can create properties that are based off other properties and not backed by a private variable (instead of using hidden fields), which you can then use for validation. For example you could have a start date and an end date property. But you could also have a NumberOfDays property that was the enddate - startdate. Then if NumberOfDays is < 0 you throw up a validation error because your start date cannot be after your end date. Sorry my reply took so long, I was away on holiday :)